# Upload new package version to the nuget.org

Tags: upload, package, nuget

I 've tried to upload a new verion of my package. I have not seen any special instructions for new version uploading, so i have tried to repeat the usual steps with the nuget.exe:

1) create .nuspec file

2) correct generated .nuspec file. Package id was not changed so it is simmilar to the already existing package name. Also i've correct dll name, version (1.0.0->1.1.1) and description

3) create .Nupkg file.

But when i am trying to upload new package, it ends up with an error:
'The title of your package, 'Gin', is similar to the ID of an existing package, which can cause confusion with our users. Please modify the title of your package and try uploading again.'

Yes of coruse, previous Gin-package is already in the nuget. So what am i missing?
How can i upload a new version of my package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs if your title and/or assembly name of new version package differs from the origin title and/or assembly name.

Comment: Happened to me had to check the assemblyinfo file